# Ubuntu booting into emergency mode

Tags: dual-boot, fsck, disk-management

I have dual-booted Ubuntu 20.04.

I suspect there is problem with disk consistency and I can't boot into Ubuntu.
Last time I was using my PC it powered off because the battery drained to 0%.

Now on boot, my system is showing `fsck excited with error code 1`, and entering into emergency mode. It gave me this message:

```
[    0.111093] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
/dev/sda8 recovering journal
/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda8: 249734/3743744 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 3591902/14969600 blocks
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
```

Comment: You've provided no details of your dual boot system, and unless that other system performs file-system changes (ie. `mount` and then changes files) I'd validate the health of your drive as issues like this should not occur without a reason (*as I'd expect the owner/operator to have suspicions on possible causes*).   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: What PC are you using? Can you tell us the brand, architecture, and model, please?